# throwing a boost::shared_ptr< customException>

Tags: c++, exception, shared-ptr, stack-unwinding

is there any pitfall of the following;

```
 if (someCondition)
   throw boost::shared_ptr<SomeException>( new SomeException( "foo!" ) );

 ...

 catch( const boost::shared_ptr<SomeException>& expRef )
 {
 }
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is unusual?  Why do you want to throw a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Besides the fact that you are complicating code, using a less performing construct (dynamically allocation) for something that can be written simpler and whose performance would be better... I cannot think of any other pitfall.

Comment: Throwing shared_ptr enables propagating the exception across an asynch boundary without slicing or having to implement clone on your exception classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a pitfall.  You won't be able to catch based on base classes:

```
void f()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("look here");
}
void g()
{
  throw boost::shared_ptr<std::runtime_error>("look here");
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    f();
  }
  catch ( std::exception const& e) {}

  try { g(); }
  catch ( boost::shared_ptr<std::exception> const& e) {} // no work
}
```

You could of course make it throw on base, but then you can't catch the derived.

So yeah...don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid throwing by pointer, and prefer [throwing by value](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.12) and [catching by (const) reference](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.13).

Using a smart pointer is a way of simplifying resource management when using pointers, but if you can avoid using pointers altogether, it will be simpler doing so. Just throw a value.

Comment: +1, this is as good an answer as Crazy Eddie's; the reason i picked his is 1) i didn't thought about what he said before, while i was aware of the fact that you mentioned 2) you can only have one right answer per question

Answer (score 1):

The only pitfall I can see is that you are doing something the hard way, when you don't have to.  :-)

Normally you use a shared_pointer to manage the lifetime of an object, when that is not obvious otherwise. Here it is clear that it is not **your** responsibility to manage the exceptions thrown. The compiler will have to do that for you!

When the exception is handled, the runtime will destroy the shared_pointer that will then destroy the exception object. Otherwise the runtime would have destroyed the exception object directly! What do you gain?